# Possible override for black screen after changing the gpu?

Tags: data-recovery, screen, gpu

I recently installed Ubuntu as I need to learn Fortran. 
Meanwhile I bought new GPU - r7 370. When I installed it into motherboard and started Ubuntu I was greeted with black screen, I think that system loaded but didn't show anything.

I tried to install some drivers but the result was the same, I only could get to Ubuntu via integrated gpu.

Anyhow, I managed to go around this problem, but I don't understand why and how:
After getting into grub I go into recovery mode and there... I just resume normal booting sequence by pressing "resume". And now I'm here in Ubuntu writing this. 
Any idea why this happens ? Any idea how to make this permanent, instead of following those few steps every time I need to power up this system ?